# Using a memory stream with TIFF multipage information in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, tiff

I am creating a multipage TIFF from 2 bitmaps. I am able to save it to an external file and then open the TIFF. But I am trying to do the same but with a memory stream. This is the TIFF encoding section. if instead of MemoryStream ms, I used a file string everything works fine.

```
    Encoder encoder = Encoder.SaveFlag;
    ImageCodecInfo encoderInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().First(i => i.MimeType == "image/tiff");
    EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
    encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);

    // Save the first frame of the multi page tiff
    Bitmap firstImage = firstBitmap;

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    firstImage.Save(ms, encoderInfo, encoderParameters);

    encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);

    Bitmap img = secondBitmap;
    firstImage.SaveAdd(img, encoderParameters);

    // Close out the file
    encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
    firstImage.SaveAdd(encoderParameters);
```

the problems is when I try to decode the stream with:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
```

I seem to lose the TIFF encoding information.

Any help?

Comment: What does "seem to lose the TIFF encoding information" mean?  Is your resulting bitmap a) garbage, b) only the first page, c) throws exception...